# Query for adding totals sum

Tags: mysql, sql

Table1

```
ID, ANumber, Type, Amount, Date
1, 00010, 400, 10, 2016-11-16
2, 00011, 600, 20, 2016-11-12
3, 00012, 600, 10, 2016-11-13
4, 00013, 500, 30, 2016-11-17
5, 00014, 400, 40, 2016-11-19
```

Results:

```
400, 60
600, 30
500, 30
totals, 110
```

I want to add the totals. this is an existing table i can only SELECT.

This is my query. i don't know how to add the totals

```
SELECT Type, SUM(Amount)
FROM table1
GROUP BY Type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `with rollup`:

```
select type, sum(amount)
from t
group by type with rollup;
```

Note:  The final group will have `NULL` for the `type` rather than `totals`.  You can use `coalesce()` to get whatever value you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can always sum the initial values you returned in your initial query to generate a total:

```
SELECT SUM(sums.`sum`) AS 'total' FROM (SELECT SUM(`Amount`) AS 'sum' FROM `table1` GROUP BY `Type`) sums
```